# Are fermented foods off topic for Seasoned Advice?

Tags: support, scope

I have a question about making miso paste but fermentation is marked as off-topic. Does that include fermented foods?

> Miso paste  is fermented soy bean paste

Source: [http://japanese-cooking-class-tokyo-mari.com/](http://japanese-cooking-class-tokyo-mari.com/recipe/2013/11/01/how-to-make-miso-paste-home-made-miso-recipe/)

Answer (score 6):

Fermented foods are on topic. You are welcome to ask about miso, and also other fermented food such as sauerkraut and pickles.

I guess the confusion may come from the point

> Wine-making, Brewing, Distillation and Fermentation

This means that the site doesn't cover the making of alcoholic beverages from scratch, such as making your own beer. The "fermentation" part is to be understood as fermentation in the context of brewing alcohol. Fermentation as part of food production is ok.

If you have questions about the preparation of typical alcoholic drinks, homebrew.stackexchange is the right place. We tend to keep questions from the gray area about fermented drinks with low alcohol content, such as kefir or yeast carbonated soda.

Comment: Thanks for citing this to clarify [this question about Kvass/Borscht fermentation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/119537/warm-vegetable-fermentation-at-30c-85f-when-is-it-used-and-what-are-the-m?noredirect=1#comment193851_119537) - after examination of the Homebrew on-topic rules and Meta site they really do focus in hard on the alcohol side, so food fermentation does seem like a better fit over here, even though there are more kvass fermentation questions on HB.SE. Agreed that the line on the Seasoned Advice On Topic guidelines may benefit from some disambiguation.